# Converging to better solutions by running RRTstar for multiple Iterations

Tags: algorithm, path-planning, autonomous-car, rrt

In the Literature I have read so far, I saw RRT star was running in multiple loops to converge to a better solution ( near optimal). I was wondering how I could implement the same, as most pseudocodes don't explain that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RRT* indeed runs in multiple iterations to converge to an asymptotically-optimal solution.

In simple words: you could understand RRT* as an RRT, but with: **1)** the stopping criteria being time/iterations instead of reaching the goal node and **2)** with an extra *re-wiring* step that chooses, inside of a neighborhood of radius *r* from your *already wired* sample, the neighbor that can see its path cost more reduced, and attempts to connect to it. With this last methodology you get more *styled* branches which lead faster to the goal.

Here you got a video that explains [RRT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFc6g9KrnOk).

The same author makes another video on [RRT*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JM7kmWE8Gtc) (in particular the *re-wiring* process).

Comment: How is the goal corresponded out of the explored nodes if that is the case?

Comment: @Ajin2305 the goal node has already been found, then you keep iterating to refine the branches. You do not lose the goal node you found, but might find a new path to it due to this refinement. Is that an answer to your comment?

Comment: I got the following characteristics for convergence, is it right? https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/16318/rrt-star-convergence