# RRT star Convergence

Tags: motion-planning, matlab, algorithm, rrt

**My Code gives the following convergence characteristics, I wanted to know if it is correct**
[image: Convergence for non-holonomic body 2000 iterations]

Updated code

{

```
    %Basic RRT star algorithm for non-holonomic body with obstacles
    close all
    clc
   clear all
   %Map and Initialization Data
   x_max = 100;
y_max = 100;
obs1 = [30,0,20,20];
obs2=  [30,60,20,20];
EPS = 5; % Step Size
Iter = 2000;

q_start.pos = [10 10];
q_start.cost = 0;
q_start.parent = 0;
q_start.child=[];
q_goal.pos = [90,90];
q_goal.cost = 1e9;
q_goal.child=[];
q_new.pos =[0,0];
q_new.cost=0;
q_new.parent=0;
q_new.child=[];
goal_reached=0;
tree(1) = q_start;
figure(1)
axis([0 x_max 0 y_max])
rectangle('Position',obs1,'FaceColor','b')
rectangle('Position',obs2,'FaceColor','b')
hold on
plot(q_start.pos(1),q_start.pos(2),'.','MarkerSize',10,'Color','m')
plot(q_goal.pos(1),q_goal.pos(2),'.','MarkerSize',10,'Color','b')
goal_nodes=[];
best_goal=[];
finalnodes=[];
  goals=0;
fc=[];
t=cputime;
for i=1:1:Iter
    q_rand=random_state(x_max,y_max);%Sampling a random state from the configuration space
    [q_near,val,idx] = nearest_neighbour(q_rand,tree); % Obtaining the nearest neighbour from the tree and its distance from q_rand
     q_new.pos=move(q_rand,q_near.pos,val,EPS);

 %Checking if goal has been reached    
  stat= distance(q_rand,q_goal.pos);
        if (stat<=4 &&~isCollision(q_rand,q_near.pos,obs1)&&~isCollision(q_rand,q_rand,obs2))
            goal_reached = 1;
            goals=goals+1;
            goal_nodes(goals,:)=q_rand;
            q_new.pos=q_rand;
        end





   if(~isCollision(q_new.pos,q_near.pos,obs1)&&~isCollision(q_new.pos,q_near.pos,obs2))

   %line([q_near.pos(1), q_new.pos(1)], [q_near.pos(2), q_new.pos(2)], 'Color', 'k', 'LineWidth', 1);
        q_new.cost = distance(q_new.pos, q_near.pos) + q_near.cost;

    % Within a radius of r, find all existing nodes
        q_nearest = [];
        r = 10;
        neighbor_count = 0;
        ni=[];
        for j = 1:1:length(tree)
            if (noCollision(tree(j).pos,q_new.pos,obs1)&&noCollision(tree(j).pos,q_new.pos,obs2)&&distance(tree(j).pos, q_new.pos) <= r)
                neighbor_count = neighbor_count+1;
                q_nearest(neighbor_count).pos = tree(j).pos;
                q_nearest(neighbor_count).cost = tree(j).cost;
                ni=[ni,j];
            end
        end

        % Initialize cost to currently known value
        q_min = q_near;
        C_min = q_new.cost;

        % Iterate through all nearest neighbors to find alternate lower
        % cost paths

        for k = 1:1:length(q_nearest)
            if (q_nearest(k).cost + distance(q_nearest(k).pos, q_new.pos) < C_min)
                q_min = q_nearest(k);
                C_min = q_nearest(k).cost + distance(q_nearest(k).pos, q_new.pos);           

            end
        end

        % Update parent to least cost-from node
        for j = 1:1:length(tree)
            if tree(j).pos == q_min.pos  
                q_new.parent = j;
                q_new.cost = C_min;
                break
            end
        end


        % Add to tree
        tree = [tree,q_new];
        tree(q_new.parent).child=[tree(q_new.parent).child,length(tree)];

      %Rewire
      %Iterate through all nearest neighbors to rewire them with lower cost
      %path
        for k = 1:1:length(q_nearest)
            if ( q_new.cost + distance(q_nearest(k).pos, q_new.pos) < q_nearest(k).cost)
                tree(ni(k)).parent=length(tree);
                tree(ni(k)).cost= q_new.cost + distance(q_nearest(k).pos, q_new.pos);
                updatecost(tree,ni(k)); %Update cost of children

            end
        end   
   end
  best_cost=1e9; 
  best_goalindex=0;
    if(goal_reached)

for k=1:1:length(goal_nodes(:,2))
  for j = 1:1:length(tree)
      if(tree(j).pos(1)==goal_nodes(k,1)&&tree(j).pos(2)==goal_nodes(k,2)&&tree(j).cost<best_cost)
            best_goal=tree(j);
            best_cost=tree(j).cost;
            best_goalindex=j;

      end

  end    
end

% Search backwards from goal to start to find the optimal least cost path
q_goal.parent = best_goalindex;
q_end = q_goal;
finalcost=0;
tree = [tree q_goal];
while q_end.parent ~= 0
    start = q_end.parent;
    finalcost=finalcost+distance(q_end.pos,tree(start).pos);
    plot(q_end.pos(1),q_end.pos(2),'*','Color','r')
    line([q_end.pos(1), tree(start).pos(1)], [q_end.pos(2), tree(start).pos(2)], 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
    hold on
    q_end = tree(start);
end
   finalnodes=[finalnodes,i];
   fc=[fc,finalcost];
   drawnow
    end
end
e=cputime-t
figure(2)
plot(finalnodes,fc);
title('RRT* Convergence')
xlabel('Iteration')
ylabel('Path Cost')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, at every iteration your RRT* should give a more optimized path once it has found it. The fluctuations are strange. You should try to get a convergence similar to [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Effect-of-path-rewiring-on-convergence-rate-and-path-length_fig6_259680822).